# WordPress do_shortcode in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am using do_shortcode hook that is preventing "Add to cart" to show non-paid members.

I have used the following code and the "Add to cart" doesn't seem to work.

```
    else{
echo do_shortcode( '[ihc-hide-content ihc_mb_type="show" ihc_mb_who="1" ihc_mb_template="1" ]' . '<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>' . '[/ihc-hide-content]" );
');
```

It's being displayed as :

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOhKy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
else{
    echo do_shortcode( 
        '[ihc-hide-content ihc_mb_type="show" ihc_mb_who="1" ihc_mb_template="1" ]' . 
            '<button 
                type="submit" 
                name="add-to-cart" 
                value="
                    '.<?php 
                            esc_attr( $product->get_id() )
                        ?>.'"
                class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
                '.<?php 
                    esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() )
                ?>.'
            </button>' . 
        '[/ihc-hide-content]" );
    ');
```

**UPDATE**

```
else{
    echo do_shortcode( 
        '[ihc-hide-content ihc_mb_type="show" ihc_mb_who="1" ihc_mb_template="1" ]' . 
            '<button 
                type="submit" 
                name="add-to-cart" 
                value="
                    '.
                        esc_attr( $product->get_id() )
                    .'"
                class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
                '.
                    esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() )
                .'
            </button>' . 
        '[/ihc-hide-content]" );
    ');
```

Comment: It returns an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in line 8".

Comment: @MMujtabaK Please write 'line 8' here

Comment: Line 8:                     '.<?php 
It's same as the line 8 in the code.

Comment: Thanks but it still has an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) on line 9"

Comment: @MujtabaK oh, my bad, remove ';' after echo

Comment: @MujtabaK oh, how example, remove echo, because it's echo in echo, not working. Try this variant

Comment: I removed ';' after echo - the error is still there. Can you share your version?

Comment: @MujtabaK check my second answer

Comment: I copied UPDATE answer and it still shows "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) on line 9"

Comment: @MujtabaK If I helped you, raise the answer rating and choose how correct, please. Thank you!